# Module not found: Can't resolve '@/prismicio'

Tags: next.js, prismic.io

I've started a project using Prismic + NextJS with this template: https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/prismic-blog. I've set everything up as required, and I'm getting the following error: Module not found: Can't resolve '@/prismicio'.

I haven't changed any of the important pages. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Thanks!

I've looked at all the forums, but couldn't find an answer!

Comment: Change the folder name from `@prismicio` to something else without the `@`.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` import alias requires a `jsconfig.json` (if using JavaScript) or `tsconfig.json` (if using TypeScript) in the root of your project.

Include a `compilerOptions.paths` value that maps `@` to `./src`, like this:

```json
// jsconfig.json OR tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This option can be combined with other `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json` options.

**Note**: The `@` alias is recommended by default when creating a new Next.js app with `create-next-app`.

If your editor still cannot resolve the `@` import, restart your editor to restart the TypeScript server process (`tsserver`).